# Configuring WCF For Different Environments

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, wcf

What's the best practice in a desktop application for configuring WCF services to connect do different endpoints depending on whether your in a development environment, system testing environment, production, etc...?  When I did web application development connecting to DBs, I modified the web.config to have different connection strings based on vertical.  Is it the same approach with WCF endpoints and just update the app.config file?

Thanks!

Comment: Also check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75062949/8644294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use configuration file transformation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

For example:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
   <system.serviceModel>
      <client>
         <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" address="NEW_ADDRESS"
           xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
      </client>
   </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This appears to only be supported for web.config, but not app.config for desktop apps.  Googling appears to reveal a few ways where you can kind of hack a solution together.  Does VS not have a supported way of achieving different configs for different environments?

Comment: http://gunnarpeipman.com/2013/11/using-web-config-transforms-with-app-config-files/

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the articles I found as well.  He mentions right in there that it's hacking together a solution.  I guess consensus is that Visual Studio doesn't support transformations for app.config?